# How can I listen on subscription disconnect event from appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am using appsync for graphql implementation. It works good for subscription that I don't need to maintain client connections. But I can't find a way in appsync to detect if a connection is disconnected from client.

I'd like to attach a resolver on a subscription in appsync whenever a connection is closed
by clients. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I don't think appsync supports it at all